# Position icon after Google line chart title

Tags: jquery, css, charts, google-visualization

I have a page with a Google Chart Gauge and a Google Chart Linechart.
I would like to place an icon just after the line chart title.
I use the following code to do this:

```
var e = $("text:contains('CHART TITLE')");
var off = e.offset();
$("#refreshIcon").css({
  left: off.left + e.width() + 10,
  top: off.top - e.height(),
  position: "absolute",
  'z-index': 999
});
```

Somehow the linechart conflicts with the gauge. Scenarios tested:

1) Gauge on top, line chart below: incorrect placement of icon

2) Line chart on top, gauge below: works fine

3) disable gauge drawing (just doing a return in drawGauge()): works fine

Any suggestions? Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cpadmzd4/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `position()` instead of `offset()` will give you `top`,
relative to the *document*, rather than the *offset parent*

also, since the gauge chart will affect where to position the image,
need to wait until both charts have finished drawing before setting placement

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawCharts,
  packages: ['gauge', 'corechart']
});

function drawCharts() {
  drawChart();
  drawGauges();
}

function drawGauges() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Memory', 80],
    ['CPU', 55],
  ]);

  var w = $(window).width();
  var x = Math.floor(w * 0.3);
  var h = $(window).height();
  var y = Math.floor(h * 0.3);

  var options = {
    redFrom: 90,
    redTo: 100,
    yellowFrom: 75,
    yellowTo: 90,
    minorTicks: 5,
    width: x,
    height: y,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', moveImage);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2004', 1000, 400],
    ['2005', 1170, 460],
    ['2006', 660, 1120],
    ['2007', 1030, 540]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'CHART TITLE',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', moveImage);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

function moveImage() {
  var e = $("text:contains('CHART TITLE')");
  var off = e.position();
  $("#refreshIcon").css({
    left: off.left + e.width() + 10,
    top: off.top - e.height() + 10,
    position: "absolute",
    'z-index': 999
  });
}

$(window).resize(drawCharts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>

<i id="refreshIcon" class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row1">
    <div id="curve_chart">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it absolutely helps. Thanks a lot. Fixed a problem and learned something. Great!

Comment: cheers! you may also want to inspect attr `font-size`, in order to adjust padding (`10`) -- check snippet in _Full page_ vs. not -- but performs well as is...